# SQL Server Sequence Object

Tags: sql-server-2012

While generating script I'm able to select specific database object except Sequence. Is there any way to generate scripts for specific (or) all the available Sequence.

Comment: In SSMS you should be able to right-click a sequence in the object explorer and choose 'Script sequence as...'

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to choose all the Sequences available in our DataBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, press `F7` or click view -> object explorer details:
[image]

Then select the database, Programmability, Sequences, select all sequences, right click, and choose `Script sequence as`:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Zohar, Thank you. It is working fine.I will accept this as the correct answer.